# How do I set a code coverage value in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan, test-coverage

In SonarQube, by default, code coverage is set to 80%. How can I set it to some other value?

Comment: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/quality-gates/ Might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to guess that what you're really asking is how you can configure a SonarQube project so that it REQUIRES 80% code coverage to be determined as successful.  This is determined by the "Quality Gate".  If you edit the quality gate, or create a new one, you will see that you can set the various properties that are measured, and the numbers that have to be hit.  The "code coverage" metric is just one of the several metrics it can measure and examine.

Comment: add reference site: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/quality-gates/